# How to fetch all Tags for a give ARN (Amazon Resource Name)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

I want to write a simple API (using AWS API and Lambda), which will return all tags associated with a particular resource, identified by ARN. So in API as input, We will pass ARN and API should return all tags.

We can certainly use AWS JavaScript Library to get tag info. But in that case we need to put lot many if and else so that we can call specific get tag method according to ARN resource type.

```
If (ARN is S3) 
   Call S3 Get Bucket Tagging Method
If (ARN is EC2)
   Call EC2 Describe Instance Method
```

We also explored resourcegroupstaggingapi but there is no service available to do this.

Is there any generalize way to do it?